Upgrade of openxmlsdk to 3.0.2 compilation issue in usage of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.IPackage
I am getting the following compilation error.
error C4950: 'DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Packaging::IPackage': marked as obsolete
\nvsdocument.cpp(399): note: Message: 'This is an experimental APIs and is subject to change'.
Same error occurs for DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Packaging::IPackagePart as well
It was using System::IO::Packaging::Package in openxmlsdk 2.19 ,but new openxmlsdk version(3.0.2) doesnot support it and as per document this need to be changed to DocumentFormat::OpenXml::Packaging::IPackage.
That is throwing this error now.
